# What is the difference between `my $foo` and `my ($foo)`?

Tags: perl

What is the difference between

```
my $foo
```

and

```
my ($foo)
```

Comment: I know you just picked `$a` as an example, but you got (un)lucky in that `$a` is a special variable...you should never use `my $a` or `my ($a)` in a script since it will screw with `sort`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference between `my $a` and `my ($a)`.

However, there is a world of difference between

```
my $a = some_function();
```

and

```
my ($a) = some_function();
```

The first example calls `some_function` in scalar context.  The second calls it in list context.

If your function looks like this:

```
sub some_function {
    return ( 'Larry', 'Moe', 'Curly' );
}
```

Then your results will be:

```
my $a = some_function();  # $a gets "Curly", the last element in the list.
my ($a) = some_function();  # $a gets "Larry" and the other two values are discarded.
```

Comment: It's list context not array context, to be as pedantic as possible.

Comment: Also pedantified.  Thanks @AKHolland

Comment: I would also add that `my ()` allows you to declare multiple vars as `my ($var1, $var2, @arr, %hash)` which is handy.